# Python classes combined with a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

I want to make a python class from a list of dictionaries. I tried the following but it tells me that i cant have list indices that are dictionaries.

```
class Dict_to_Class(object):
    def __init__(self, s_dict):
        for key in s_dict:
            setattr(self, key, s_dict[key])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s_dict = [{'cs': '10', 'ca': '11', 'cb': '12', 'cc': 'same'}, {'cs': '114', 'ca': '121', 'cb': '132', 'cc': 'diff'},
              {'cs': '20', 'ca': '21', 'cb': '22', 'cc': 'same'}, {'cs': '210', 'ca': '211', 'cb': '212', 'cc': 'diff'},
              {'cs': '10', 'ca': '115', 'cb': '12', 'cc': 'same'}, {'cs': '101', 'ca': '11', 'cb': '172', 'cc': 'diff'},
              {'cs': '10', 'ca': '181', 'cb': '129', 'cc': 'same'}, {'ca': '11', 'cb': '12', 'cc': 'same'}]
    result = Dict_to_Class(s_dict)
    print(type(result))
```

This was my way of testing wether it works or not.

Comment: do you want to make an instance of your class for each dict in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s_dict` is not a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries. You have to update your code accordingly to that, and access to each position using numeric indices.

If you choose one element of your list, your code works:

```
class Dict_to_Class(object):
    def __init__(self, s_dict):
        
        for key in s_dict:
            setattr(self, key, s_dict[key])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s_dict = [{'cs': '10', 'ca': '11', 'cb': '12', 'cc': 'same'}, {'cs': '114', 'ca': '121', 'cb': '132', 'cc': 'diff'},
              {'cs': '20', 'ca': '21', 'cb': '22', 'cc': 'same'}, {'cs': '210', 'ca': '211', 'cb': '212', 'cc': 'diff'},
              {'cs': '10', 'ca': '115', 'cb': '12', 'cc': 'same'}, {'cs': '101', 'ca': '11', 'cb': '172', 'cc': 'diff'},
              {'cs': '10', 'ca': '181', 'cb': '129', 'cc': 'same'}, {'ca': '11', 'cb': '12', 'cc': 'same'}]
    result = Dict_to_Class(s_dict[0])
    print(type(result))
```

This code returns:

`<class '__main__.Dict_to_Class'>`

Comment: Indeed because 1 element of my code is a dictionary. But then what im aiming at is to turn that whole list of dictionaries into an object. Basically im trying to have a situation whereby i have an object with attributes or keys which are cs, ca, cb, and cc but with the corresponding values. It can be sort of like a table so i need to make that into a class

Comment: @ManatsaMbanje so you want _multiple objects_ - one per dictionary?

Comment: @ManatsaMbanje how many objects do you want to obtain? Because in that list you have 8 instances, therefore if you iterate through that you would obtain 8 different objects. You can iterate in the main function with a for loop and pass your constructor those dictionaries instead of the list containing them.

Comment: This means that its impossible to make it into 1 object then or maybe I'm misunderstanding classes and objects.

Comment: @ManatsaMbanje I think you are misunderstanding something. Out of that list you can create 8 objects with different values for each of the 4 parameters. You could store those objects on a list afterwards, but there is no point on making a class for holding a list.

Comment: Yeah i am. Thank you for the help pertaining to my question, i need to rethink my approach to my problem.